# Setting default gateway on CentOS 7 and showing it using route and netstat -r

Tags: centos, linux-networking

I am following a tutorial found here on how to setup a gateway for each adapter and also a default gateway:

http://linux-training.be/sysadmin/ch22.html

But when I run the commands

```
$ route
```

and

```
$ netstat -r
```

the gateway does not appear as shown in the tutorial.

Here are my relevant files:

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network

NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=lvs
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1


$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

NAME=eth0
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes

HWADDR=08:00:27:47:BD:B3

IPADDR0=192.168.1.100
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0


$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=5cc476e7-c116-41f0-bcb6-129fdba369ba
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

I think I have followed everything correctly. So I don't understand why gateways does not show up as in the tutorial.

```
$ route

[root@lvs network-scripts]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

$ netstat -r

[root@lvs network-scripts]# netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: But they do show up!

Comment: But it just says gateway on default. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `netstat -nr` as opposed to `netstat -r`. Same for `route`, run `route -n` instead. This will show the actual IP address instead of the hostname.